# Multiple files from folder and subfolder

Tags: javascript

I'm making a web-based video player. I'm only able to copy-paste a single video link one by one...how can I copy-paste a whole folder video links through one command? Means for each video(files) from folder or sub-folder I have to write video src ="" code...So how can I show each and every files on web page with just folder link copy pasted on html or something.

Comment: plenty of libraires, otherwise a task for the backend. Simplest solution would be a list of all files and a for-loop. Question ahs nothing to do with HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to do, so I can't say which of these is the right fit, but:

- You might consider the [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API), which lets you drag files from the OS desktop into a webapp. That will give you an array of files that you can then work with.
- You might provide a `<textarea>` that lets a user paste a whole bunch of links, and assume that each line contains one URL. Split that text on `'\n'`, and then you've got your array.